# How to get value of each cell of Row datagridview selectedItem binded with a join of tables?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagridview

I'm trying to get the value of every cell in selected row which contains three cells in data grid view

I tried to save the selected Item in Ilist but  it gets all row and I can't
get every cell

```
        IList rows = PlanDG.SelectedItems;      
        var h = rows[0];
        var hh = rows[1];
        var hhh = rows[2];
```

I expect to get every cell but it gives me all row in var h

Comment: what is the type of `item source` ur assigning?

Comment: all of it are string type ...am sorry that my question not very clear

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use index you can do something like this

```
DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)PlanDG.SelectedItem;
string cellValue = dataRow.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
```

If you have type then I suggest a change SelectedItem as that type

**Example**

```
Factor row = PlanDG.SelectedItem as Factor;
```

Comment: It give me an Exception:Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType5`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.'

Comment: check below answer if not working posting ur item source assigning. I will change my answer.

Comment: My Item source is binded with three Different tables in data base and every column is string .... I hope that is the answer of your question

Comment: Linq Query .....var query = (from sc in cd.SubjectTeachers
                         join s in cd.Subjects on sc.IdSubject equals s.Id
                         join t in cd.Teachers on sc.IdTeacher equals t.Id
                         join b in cd.Branches on sc.IdBranch equals b.Id

                         select new { t.NickName, s.Code, b.TypeOfBranch }).ToList();
            PlanDG.ItemsSource = query;

Comment: any help . please ?

Comment: you are using anonymous type so just use proper type it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve using below code. also you can access one cell value based on index no

```
    IList rows = PlanDG.SelectedItems;      
    var h = rows[0].Cells[0];
    var hh = rows[1].Cells[0];
    var hhh = rows[2].Cells[0];
```